# Is it possible to get size of object in bytes especially list<dynamic> or map<string,dynamic>?

Tags: flutter, dart

For some reason, I am looking for an approach to get the size-of an object.
My target object is  list or map<string,dynamic>.
I am looking through the document, there is `sizeOf()` but doesn't have any arguments more.

Is there something wrong?

Comment: by size of a map do you mean the number of key-value pairs? In which case for a list you can simply use the length property of both the list and the map to get their lengths e.g `Map.length`

Comment: @Mich25educ I mean the total object size in bytes.

Comment: Why would you need to know the number of bytes?  Dart does not provide raw memory access to objects, so knowing the exact number of bytes would not be very useful.

Comment: You could write to a file and then get the length of that?

Comment: @ebg11 cant think of worse ways to do that...

Comment: @shivzuh what would another method be?

Comment: @jamesdlin maybe he want's to send them via https to a backend with a size limit per request

Comment: @harlekintiger Knowing the number of bytes of a *serialized representation* is different from knowing the size of an in-memory object.

Comment: @jamesdlin we don't know which of the two he wanted to know though

Comment: @harlekintiger OP asked for "the size of an object in bytes".   That means the in-memory size unless otherwise specified (since a serialized representation would need to specify exactly how the object would be serialized).  Now, maybe the OP doesn't understand the distinction, but I stand by my earlier statement that knowing the object size is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

This should help. But I'm not sure it is working in your case. Please test it well.

```
import 'dart:convert';


final json = yourObject.toJson();
final jsonString = jsonEncode(json);
final jsonSizeInBytes = utf8.encode(jsonString).length;
print('JSON size: $jsonSizeInBytes bytes');
```